# Future failure in Clojure

Tags: scala, clojure

In Scala a future can fail and this can be found out asynchronously:

```
f onComplete {
  case Success(_) => println("Great!")
  case Failure(t) => println("An error has occurred: " + t.getMessage)
}
```

How would you 'translate' this into Clojure? My reading leads me to believe that the Clojure future/promise model is not as powerful as Scala's, and you can't just catch the failure like this. So what to do instead?

A Scala future never needs to be asked for it's value - when it is good and ready it will tell you what happened (including whether it failed - that's the crux of this question). This is what I meant by 'asynchronously'. A Scala future can be in one of three possible states - uncompleted, completed with failure, completed with success.

A typical example of a use case in Scala is a remote call that returns a Future[T], where T is the type of what you really want to get back. If the remote JVM is down then after a timeout the `case Failure(t)` will happen.

This is quite a straightforward model to work with. In the question I was asking for a simple alternative. As a side-comment it would be good to hear that Clojure intends to adopt the Scala Futures model at some point.

Comment: My understanding is that futures are not very used in Clojure. I see a lot of talking about `core.async` instead, but I might be wrong.

Comment: futures, core.async, agents, and regular java thread-pools all have their place and none of them are good general replacements for the others

Comment: @mfirry I can see why they would be avoided. It makes no sense to be doing a 'get the value' on a future. I'm just trying to work out the simple alternative that experienced Clojure developers would actually use. For instance Om handles rolling back of client state on failure, so how failure is introduced into our code by Om will give me a hint. I'm only just starting to look at Clojure so I don't know the answer myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remember futures in Scala are monads so searched `algo.monads` and `fluokitten` for something suitable. Finally I found Lenardo Borges' `imminent` library. I think it's what you want.

With this namespace declaration in place

```
(ns imminent-proof.core
  (:require [imminent.core :as i]
            [clojure.core.match :refer [match]])
  (:import  [imminent.result Success Failure]))
```

This is the failure case

```
(-> (i/future (/ 1 0))
    (i/on-complete #(match [%]
                     [{Success v}] (prn "success: " v)
                     [{Failure e}] (prn "failure: " e))))
```

This the success case

```
(-> (i/future (Thread/sleep 1000) 42)
    (i/on-complete #(match [%]
                     [{Success v}] (prn "success: " v)
                     [{Failure e}] (prn "failure: " e))))
```

And this the timeout case

```
(-> (i/future (Thread/sleep 1000) 42)
    (i/await 500)
    (i/on-complete #(match [%]
                     [{Success v}] (prn "success: " v)
                     [{Failure e}] (prn "failure: " e))))
```

Comment: Great answer. Would be good to see it on Clojurescript too one day - Scala.js already uses Scala futures.

Comment: Hi, I'm the author of Imminent. The next release will include Clojurescript support.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if Clojure need specific construct to handle this situation with failed futures. The following line gives me the same functionality:

```
(defn f-cond[f func-ok func-fail] 
   (future (try (func-ok @f) (catch Exception e (func-fail e)))))
```

Then:

```
@(f-cond (future (throw (Exception. "hi"))) 
   identity #(println "Failed: " (.getCause %)))
```

results in

```
Failed:  #<Exception java.lang.Exception: hi>
```

Comment: ...and you would have to make sure the de-referencing (getting the value/failure) is done after a suitable timeout, which you would have to manage yourself. Something very simple in Scala becomes something quite complex in Clojure. There has to be a 'typical workaround' to this which does not (??) involve Clojure/Java futures.

Comment: What do you mean 'suitable timeout, which you manage yourself'? I don't see any timeout managing in the code above. Once you run the future, it starts executing in another thread, returning immediately. If the result of the execution (or failure) are available after sometime, dereferencing will take that time,

Comment: And dereferencing is not necessary in the code above. Instead of @(f-cond ...) you can run (f-cond ...). You will not get the execution result, but onSuccess will be executed with it, when it becomes available.

Comment: In answer to your question (suitable timeout you manage yourself) I was thinking about dereferencing when there's a good chance that the future has completed, so as not to be blocking too much, yet get the result in a timely fashion. That's the management you would have to do yourself.

Comment: Retreiving the result of a computation when there's a good chance it has completed  - how is that language specific?

Comment: It is language specific because with Scala futures (and all the rest of the reactive stuff) you don't have to block. If you don't have to block you don't have to guess when something has probably completed - you will be told.

Comment: Question: How do you block with (f-cond ...) ? Answer: you don't. Yes, it is not RP, but none of your  remarks above require reactive programming as solution. The failure will be processes asynchronously in another thread, wasn't that the question?

Comment: The question was not about threads. I want to be told (in the future) that there's a problem. I don't want to have to find it out. There is a difference between Scala and Java futures. I am looking for the best work-around this known problem of Clojure using poor-man's (Java) futures.

Answer (score 0):

the future macro is just wrapping a Java Future, and the deref reader macro is just syntax sugar for calling `.get()` against the future:

```
user=> (source future)
(defmacro future
  "Takes a body of expressions and yields a future object that will
  invoke the body in another thread, and will cache the result and
  return it on all subsequent calls to deref/@. If the computation has
  not yet finished, calls to deref/@ will block, unless the variant of
  deref with timeout is used. See also - realized?."
  {:added "1.1"}
  [& body] `(future-call (^{:once true} fn* [] ~@body)))
nil
user=> (source future-call)
(defn future-call 
  "Takes a function of no args and yields a future object that will
  invoke the function in another thread, and will cache the result and
  return it on all subsequent calls to deref/@. If the computation has
  not yet finished, calls to deref/@ will block, unless the variant
  of deref with timeout is used. See also - realized?."
  {:added "1.1"
   :static true}
  [f]
  (let [f (binding-conveyor-fn f)
        fut (.submit clojure.lang.Agent/soloExecutor ^Callable f)]
    (reify 
     clojure.lang.IDeref 
     (deref [] (deref-future fut))
     clojure.lang.IBlockingDeref
     (deref
      [ timeout-ms timeout-val]
      (deref-future fut timeout-ms timeout-val))
     clojure.lang.IPending
     (isRealized [] (.isDone fut))
     java.util.concurrent.Future
      (get [] (.get fut))
      (get [_ timeout unit] (.get fut timeout unit))
      (isCancelled [] (.isCancelled fut))
      (isDone [] (.isDone fut))
      (cancel [_ interrupt?] (.cancel fut interrupt?)))))
nil
user=>
```

So testing for failure is no different than in java: you catch an `ExecutionException`, see java doc for Future:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get()

So the solution is to catch the exception from the `deref`, as shown in other answers.